# Doctrine 2: QueryBuilder Join with subquery

Tags: php, mysql, sql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

**I need to convert native query to doctrine query.**

Native query

```
select u.*, v.browser_id
from users u
left join visits v
    on u.id = v.user_id
    and v.id = (
        select max(id) from visits v2
        where v2.user_id = u.id
    )
```

**You can see right here that I need to select users with the latest browser they used to visit**

[image]

**So to convert this query to DQL I understand that I need to do something like this**

```
        $queryBuilder->leftJoin('u.visits', 'lastVis', Join::WITH,
            // ????
        );
```

**but I don’t know what exactly. Perhaps someone will solve this quickly?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Thanks, seem I found the solution:)**

```
        $subQuery = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('MAX(vis2.id)')
            ->from(Visit::class, 'vis2')
            ->where('vis2.user = u.id');

        $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('u')
            ->from(User::class, 'u')
            ->leftJoin(
                'u.visits', 'vis',
                Join::WITH, sprintf('vis.id = (%s)', $subQuery->getDQL()),
            );
```